# Simple conditions in JQuery calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stuck with (a simple) JQuery problem. I'm trying to make a simple real-time cost calculator with 1 input field. Now, I'd like to use different price ranges for the input variable. For example:

- Input value 1-15 is 4 per item;
- Input value 16-100 is 3 per item;
- Input value 100-200 is 2 per item;
- With input values above 200 the result is 'Don't eat all the gummballs'.

This is what I have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gummball').keyup(function() {
    $('#result').text($('#gummball').val() * 1.5);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Price of gummball:</label><input name="gummball" id="gummball" type="text" />
<br /> Total: &euro; <span id="result"></span>
```

I hope one of you guys can help me out! :)

Comment: Do you know how to use if statement in JS? What about declaring/assigning to/reading value of variables?

Comment: Learn to use `if` block https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Also tag with [tag:javascript] please.

Comment: I think it should be `Input value 101-200 is 2 per item;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gummball').keyup(function() {
    if($('#gummball').val() > 0 && $('#gummball').val() < 16) {
     $('#result').text($('#gummball').val() * 4);
    }
    if($('#gummball').val() > 15 && $('#gummball').val() < 101) {
     $('#result').text($('#gummball').val() * 3);
    }
    if($('#gummball').val() > 100 && $('#gummball').val() < 201) {
     $('#result').text($('#gummball').val() * 2);
    }
    if($('#gummball').val() > 200) {
     $('#result').text('Don`t eat all the gummballs');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Price of gummball:</label>
<input name="gummball" id="gummball" type="text" />
<br /> Total: &euro; <span id="result"></span>
```

Comment: @marcuse You should not leave such comments: [Is it acceptable to write a thank you in a comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126180)

Comment: @user202729 Don't try to be too much of a wiseacre! This answer _with only code_ is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#gummball').keyup(function() {
  if($('#gummball').val() <= 200)
    $('#result').html($('#gummball').val() * 1.5);
  else
    $('#result').html(($('#gummball').val() * 1.5) + " <br><b>Don't eat all the gummballs</b>");   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Price of gummball:</label><input name="gummball" id="gummball" type="text" />
<br /> Total: &euro; <span id="result"></span>
```